# Customized certificates

Tags: ssl

I dont know how to search for something like this, but here is what I like to do:

I have an internet accessible LAMP application that uses HTTPS: The user must login to access it.

I would like to make it so that each authenticated user can only access it from authorized workstations.

Is there a way to create a certificate that only is valid from the workstation or mobile device it was created on?

Maybe it can be based on a hardware serial # or something else specific to that machine.

Any docs that explain how to do this?

Comment: The answer that jumps out to me is to just use AES/private key, but I think I may be overlooking what you want in favor of the obvious. Are you trying to ensure that the key absolutely cannot be exported?

Comment: I need to prevent a user from exporting the certificate and using it on another machine. I want to know that they can't login from a public machine for example, but can login only from a laptop that was given to them.

Comment: Maby I'm mistaken but isn't server sending certificate to client not the other way? Server only knows for sure the IP address of client. Maby you should set restriction for IP or maby restrictions for MAC address on router if it is local network (unfotunetly mac can be easily changed)?

Comment: The big issues here is that a user on a public computer could be open to attack by keystroke capturing trojans. Also the user could forget to logout and leave the app open to the next person. Yes, a Mac address can be changed easily. The only other way I can think of is using the computers hardware (E.g a serial number)

Comment: @piotrekkr no, what the OP is asking about is called client-side authentication, and it's widely used in SSL/TLS

Comment: @Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS Corp you are right didn't know about that :) Back to the question, you can't protect if user forget to logout, it's this person fault. If you want to send informations about hardware to server you should write application that checks hardware info than make some hash key and send it to server for authentication. Againt it won't protect against user who forget to logout.

Comment: I know next to nothing about Apache but I know with an RSA key you can mark it as non-exportable. At least I've done so on network devices.

Comment: I want to block users logging in from public computers. I guess I can write a small app they need to install to send the default MAC addresses or maybe some checksummed root file.

Comment: So my solution is as follows: Create a small client side app that transmits the client's MAC address to the server. If the server accepts it, the client side app launches the browser.

Comment: @user603749 Just make login token expire in short period of time, then even if the user forgets to logout, the token will become invalid quickly. This is simpler to implement and more error-prone.

Comment: @Eugene That would be annoying expiring them when they are on their own system and prompting every couple of minutes. Also it wouldn't stop a trojan on a public machine from capturing keystrokes. I am somewhat surprised that there is no protocol built in to browsers and certificates for such situations.

Comment: @user603749 you are misunderstanding certificates. They were designed for different purpose. Forget about them in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certificates authenticate users (in wide meaning), not particular hardware.

For any application that needs to be bound to specific hardware you should search for other ways, which would involve custom code written for each platform and maybe even hardware (long time ago LPT dongles were used, then they were replaced by USB dongles).

But it's easier to review your application and business design.